# I want to substitute variables for Worksheet and Table names in an AutoFilter script

Tags: excel, variables, datatable, autofilter, vba

On an excel worksheet, I am using a dropdown list to change the contents of a column next to a list of items. Based on the dropdown list selection, an "X" appears next to the appropriate items.

[Filter] [Items]

[X] [Item A]

[ ] [Item B]

[X] [Item C]

To hide the rows without an "X", I am using the script below to automatically refresh the column filter so the rows appear and disappear based on the list dropdown selection.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table356")
         .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

This works fine with absolute references, however, I want to use the worksheet as a template and do not want to manually update the Sheet and Table names every time the user creates a new worksheet.

Here are my previous attempts to create variable items:

```
Dim MyNewSheet As Worksheet
Dim MetricsList As Range

Set MyNewSheet = ActiveSheet
Set MetricsList = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:V88")
```

NOTE: It is preferable to create a table variable, rather than a range of cells.

Can you provide variables for this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one *Table* on the new worksheet, then we don't need a variable for the *ListObject*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
             .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

will do the trick.